# Is possible make a UITextField like this?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

Situation: I want to use a custom `UITextField` class for my textField in a xcode project. 
I want to the textField look like this:

[image: My text field]

I had no problems in making the edges rounded, and change the color of my placeholder,  but I have no idea how to keep the bottom edges flat and draw a black border only on the bottom.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class GrayTextField: UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = .grayf1f1f1
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override var placeholder: String? {
        didSet {
            let attributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .thin)]
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

And my current result:

[image: Current result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer, still there is some issue in bottom left and right corner.

To achieve exact result, change your `UITextField Border Style` to `No Border`.

[image]

**Padding for Text:**

```
class GrayTextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 5)

    ..... Your Exact Code .....

    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
}
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some researching, i do it. 
Here if my final code:

```
import UIKit

class GrayTextField: UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = .grayf1f1f1
        clipsToBounds = true

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape

        addBottomBorder(with: .darkGray, andWidth: 1)
    }


    override var placeholder: String? {
        didSet {
            let attributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .thin)]
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: attributes)
        }
    }

    func addBottomBorder(with color: UIColor?, andWidth borderWidth: CGFloat) {
        let border = UIView()
        border.backgroundColor = color
        border.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - borderWidth, width: frame.size.width, height: borderWidth)
        addSubview(border)
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]